# Ошибка при установке gulp-файлов в другой проект

Tags: gulp, npm

Всем привет. Уже второй день не могу исправить эту ошибку. Все варианты, которые нашёл в гугле не сработали. При добавлении gulp-файлов в новый проект, и вводе команды "npm i" происходит ошибка. Работаю через терминал "VS Code", который открывается от имени администратора.

Через "PowerShell" делал тоже самое. Сначала изменял путь "cd <путь к папке с проектом>" —> "npm i", инициализация удавалась, но после, перейдя назад в терминал "VS Code", снова были ошибки. Gulp не запускался.

Пробовал установить "python 2.7" - тщетно.

Пожалуйста, помогите решить данную проблему.

```js
$ npm i
npm WARN deprecated source - map - url @0 .4 .1: See https: //github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
  npm WARN deprecated urix @0 .1 .0: Please see https: //github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
  npm WARN deprecated har - validator @5 .1 .5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source - map - resolve @0 .5 .3: See https: //github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
  npm WARN deprecated chokidar @2 .1 .8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15 x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve - url @0 .2 .1: https: //github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
  npm WARN deprecated uuid @3 .4 .0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher.Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.See https: //v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
  npm WARN deprecated request @2 .88 .2: request has been deprecated, see https: //github.com/request/request/issues/3142
  npm WARN deprecated svgo @1 .3 .2: This SVGO version is no longer supported.Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar @2 .2 .2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates.Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR!code 1
npm ERR!path A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ node - sass
npm ERR!command failed
npm ERR!command C: \Windows\ system32\ cmd.exe / d / s / c node scripts / build.js
npm ERR!Building: C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node.exe A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ node - gyp\ bin\ node - gyp.js rebuild--verbose--libsass_ext = --libsass_cflags = --libsass_ldflags = --libsass_library =
  npm ERR!gyp info it worked
if it ends with ok
npm ERR!gyp verb cli[
  npm ERR!gyp verb cli 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  npm ERR!gyp verb cli 'A:\\Programming\\PROJECTS\\portfolio\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
  npm ERR!gyp verb cli 'rebuild',
  npm ERR!gyp verb cli '--verbose',
  npm ERR!gyp verb cli '--libsass_ext=',
  npm ERR!gyp verb cli '--libsass_cflags=',
  npm ERR!gyp verb cli '--libsass_ldflags=',
  npm ERR!gyp verb cli '--libsass_library='
  npm ERR!gyp verb cli]
npm ERR!gyp info using node - gyp @3 .8 .0
npm ERR!gyp info using node @16 .14 .0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR!gyp verb command rebuild[]
npm ERR!gyp verb command clean[]
npm ERR!gyp verb clean removing "build"
directory
npm ERR!gyp verb command configure[]
npm ERR!gyp verb check python checking
for Python executable "c:python27python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed Error: not found: c: python27python.exe
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at getNotFoundError(A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ which\ which.js: 13: 12)
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at F(A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ which\ which.js: 68: 19)
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at E(A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ which\ which.js: 80: 29)
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ which\ which.js: 89: 16
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ isexe\ index.js: 42: 5
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ isexe\ windows.js: 36: 5
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at FSReqCallback.oncomplete(node: fs: 198: 21)
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed c: python27python.exe Error: not found: c: python27python.exe
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at getNotFoundError(A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ which\ which.js: 13: 12)
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at F(A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ which\ which.js: 68: 19)
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at E(A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ which\ which.js: 80: 29)
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ which\ which.js: 89: 16
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ isexe\ index.js: 42: 5
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ isexe\ windows.js: 36: 5
npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
failed at FSReqCallback.oncomplete(node: fs: 198: 21) {
  npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
  failed code: 'ENOENT'
  npm ERR!gyp verb `which`
  failed
}
npm ERR!gyp verb could not find "c:python27python.exe".checking python launcher
npm ERR!gyp verb could not find "c:python27python.exe".guessing location
npm ERR!gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C: \Python27\ python.exe
npm ERR!gyp ERR!configure error
npm ERR!gyp ERR!stack Error: Can 't find Python executable "c:python27python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR!gyp ERR!stack at PythonFinder.failNoPython(A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ node - gyp\ lib\ configure.js: 484: 19) npm ERR!gyp ERR!stack at PythonFinder. < anonymous > (A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ node - gyp\ lib\ configure.js: 509: 16)
npm ERR!gyp ERR!stack at callback(A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ graceful - fs\ polyfills.js: 299: 20)
npm ERR!gyp ERR!stack at FSReqCallback.oncomplete(node: fs: 198: 21)
npm ERR!gyp ERR!System Windows_NT 10.0 .19043
npm ERR!gyp ERR!command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
"A:\\Programming\\PROJECTS\\portfolio\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
"rebuild"
"--verbose"
"--libsass_ext="
"--libsass_cflags="
"--libsass_ldflags="
"--libsass_library="
npm ERR!gyp ERR!cwd A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ node - sass
npm ERR!gyp ERR!node - v v16 .14 .0
npm ERR!gyp ERR!node - gyp - v v3 .8 .0
npm ERR!gyp ERR!not ok
npm ERR!Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR!A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!C: \Users\ Алексей\ AppData\ Local\ npm - cache\ _logs\ 2022 - 03 - 29 T06_01_29_705Z - debug - 0. log
```

Чуть позже скопировал в проект другие gulp-файлы, кое-как инициализация npm получилась. Но при попытке установить gulp, выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```js
$ gulp
  [11: 42: 26] Local gulp not found in A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio[11: 42: 26] Try running: npm install gulp

Alex @DESKTOP - 4 SBSU3O MINGW64 / a / Programming / PROJECTS / portfolio(main)
$ npm i - g gulp
npm WARN deprecated source - map - url @0 .4 .1: See https: //github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
  npm WARN deprecated urix @0 .1 .0: Please see https: //github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
  npm WARN deprecated source - map - resolve @0 .5 .3: See https: //github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
  npm WARN deprecated chokidar @2 .1 .8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15 x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve - url @0 .2 .1: https: //github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

  changed 349 packages, and audited 350 packages in 10 s

8 packages are looking
for funding
run `npm fund`
for details

5 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues(including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix--force

Run `npm audit`
for details.
```

```js
$ npm install gulpjs / gulp.git #4.0 --save-dev~
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! The git reference could not be found
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects checkout 4.0
npm ERR! error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-29T09_13_30_669Z-debug-0.log
```

```js
gulp
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js: 47: 5
at req_(A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ natives\ index.js: 143: 24)
at Object.req[as require](A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ natives\ index.js: 55: 10)
at Object. < anonymous > (A: \Programming\ PROJECTS\ portfolio\ node_modules\ vinyl - fs\ node_modules\ graceful - fs\ fs.js: 1: 37)
at Module._compile(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 1103: 14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 1155: 10)
at Module.load(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 981: 32)
at Function.Module._load(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 822: 12)
at Module.require(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 1005: 19)
at require(node: internal / modules / cjs / helpers: 102: 18)
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась следующим образом.
В файле "gulpfile.js", заменить "const":

```js
const gulp = require("gulp");
const browserSync = require("browser-sync");
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
```

на "import":

```js
import gulp from "gulp";
import browserSync from "browser-sync";
import dartSass from 'sass';
import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';
const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);
import rename from "gulp-rename";
import autoprefixer from "gulp-autoprefixer";
import cleanCSS from "gulp-clean-css";
import imagemin from "gulp-imagemin";
import htmlmin from "gulp-htmlmin";
```

И в файле "package.json", подключить модули:

```js
"type": "module",
```